# why my laravel migrations work on every database but one?

Tags: php, migration, schema, laravel

It's a little funny but since I choose my database name as "shahkelid", I'm not able to create "users" table using laravel migrations. Any other table name would work! Everything works great when I use an other database name (I did not forget to update the database.php config file) so I'm 100% sure that my Schema class is written correctly.

The only thing that I don't understand is that why I get this error when I change my database name to "shahkelid"?

This is the error I receive in the terminal:

```
     [Exception]                                                                  
      SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shahkelid.users'  
       doesn't exist (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_  
      increment primary key, `username` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar  
      (255) not null, `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, `updated_at` tim  
      estamp default 0 not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_  
      ci) (Bindings: array (                                                       
      ))
```

By the I have worked with this database before, I just tried to remove the whole database and rebuild it using migrations. But it doesn't work any more.

```
UPDATE: 
Migration Schema -> 

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Database Config -> 
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'shahkelid',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'root',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

Note: When I run the migrations I'm sure that laravel can connect and find the correct database, because migration table is created, but the problem is that it returns that error when it want to create users table. I'm also sure that my schema syntax is correct because It is working correct when I choose an other name for my table.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part from your database.php file and the relevant migration code?

Comment: sure, checkout the updates.

Comment: Can you please post the whole code of your migration and the User Model? make sure your migration uses `Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface` and `Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface` [Try this guide](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-uber-quick-start-with-auth-guide)